# Google Maps Embed in html form and save user selected location in MYSQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-maps

I am a newbie and I am trying to embed google maps in an HTML form.
This link helped me
http://www.w3schools.com/googleapi/google_maps_basic.asp
but it had no provision for saving user selected location in database.
Is that possible? If so, how can I implement it? I really appreciate help from you guys.

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>



<script>
function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
zoom:5,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<script>
function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
zoom:5,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
document.getElementById('lat').value= 51.508742
document.getElementById('lng').value= -0.120850  

// marker drag event
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag',function(event) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
});

//marker drag event end
google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
    document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="maps.php" method="post">
    Select your location
    <input type='hidden' name='lat' id='lat'>  
    <input type='hidden' name='lng' id='lng'> 
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

and here is the maps.php file which is used to retrieve the variables "lat" and"lng"

```
<?php

$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lng = $_POST['lng'];

echo "Latitude is" .$lat. "and longitude is" .$lng;

?>
```

I am getting a fixed value of longitude and latitude every time in maps.html. Why doesn't it update?

Comment: You'll need to look into MySQL for database management and you'll want to look into PHP to query the database.

Comment: that is for saving part if I am not wrong. What comes first is retrieving what location user has selected. I am stuck at this part.

Comment: Your question was how to "save the user selected location in database" it didn't say anything about retrieving it. You'll need to use the Google maps API and that link you have in your original post gives you a step by step tutorial on how to use it. What problems are you having, you didn't say what youve tried and what problems you've run into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take hidden field into your html form and set value by `javascript`. try as below.

**HTML:**

```
<input type='hidden' name='lat' id='lat'>  
<input type='hidden' name='lng' id='lng'>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    document.getElementById('lat').value= 51.508742
    document.getElementById('lng').value= -0.120850  

    // marker drag event
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'drag',function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
    });

    //marker drag event end
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {
        document.getElementById('lat').value = event.latLng.lat();
        document.getElementById('lng').value = event.latLng.lng();
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


</script>
```

**Note:** As google provide many event listeners so you can use as per your need. Here is the reference link just check it out and use as per your requirements. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bn40xt56/)

Comment: How do you update the hidden form as the map is panned and zoomed around?

Comment: @bcdan you can set that hidden field value in specific event callback function.

Comment: so when the user selects a location in the google map, I'll get it's latitude and longitude in the variables 'lat' and 'lng' respectively?

Comment: @EricCartman yes you will get lat long that you need to pass to the form and store into the database so you can use that further in your application/site.

Comment: Alright. And as @bcdan mentioned what if the user pans or zooms the map? Will it automatically update?

Comment: @vipulsorathiya Thanks for fixing that. Your answer would have been flat-out wrong if it were not there. By the way, I would not have thought of using a hidden form. +1

Comment: @bcdan thanks for +1, google provide various event listeners as per our needs like map click, zoom_changed etc.. so we can get set lat long in all these callback functions.

Comment: @Vipul Sir, I've updated the question according to your answer. Can you help me with this bug?

Comment: @EricCartman I have added JSFIDDLE Demo. you can check it out when you move marker it will set lat long value to your html hidden field.